# No Sprite Editor Window Registered (Windows 10)

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-development

This is my Time of Using Stack Overflow because i'm stuck here.
I installed the latest version of Unity on my PC with Windows 10 20H2 but after launching it the sprite editor doesn't work and i realized it is well installed but not working i am about to create a simple game and need your help to work around this problem.
[Pop Up after Launching Sprite Editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uvxhk.png)

[Sprite Package already Installed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jGpxX.png)

I really need responses as fast as possible.
I don't know if it's normal but my Sprites folder are all empty except the Package.json file

Comment: Based on the console log your install is corrupted, maybe reinstalling unity will solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks, I installed another version and it is working

Comment: I've added it as an answer, if it solved your problem I'd appreciate if you accepted it as the correct answer

Answer (score 1):

Your unity installation is corrupted you should reinstall Unity, it might solve your problem.